# Occurence of NaN in softmax & JIT issues

Tags: python, nan, jit, jax

I'm trying to implement the Transformer architecture from scratch using Jax. I find three issues while training:

1. `jax.disable_jit()` does not remove implicit jit compilations.
2. Why does `jax.nn.softmax` calls `_softmax_deprecated` by default?
3. I'm encountering NaNs in subtraction inside `_softmax_deprecated`: `unnormalized = jnp.exp(x - lax.stop_gradient(x_max))`
   I'll attach the code for your reference if needed:

```py
class SelfAttention(eqx.Module):
    def __call__(self, query, key, value, mask):
        scaled_dot_prod = query @ jnp.transpose(key, (0, 2, 1)) / jnp.sqrt(query.shape[-1])
        scaled_dot_prod = mask + scaled_dot_prod
        return (jax.nn.softmax(scaled_dot_prod) @ value)

def create_mask(arr):
    return jnp.where(arr == 0, np.NINF, 0)

def loss(model, X, y, X_mask, y_mask, labels):
    y_pred = jnp.log(predict(model, X, y, X_mask, y_mask))
    y_pred = jnp.where(labels==0, 0, jnp.take(y_pred, labels, axis=-1))
    count = jnp.count_nonzero(y_pred)
    return -jnp.sum(y_pred)/count

with jax.disable_jit():
    for e in range(EPOCHS):
        total_loss = 0
        num_batches = 0
        total_tokens = 0
        for i, (Xbt, ybt, labelbt) in enumerate(dataloader(Xtr, ytr, SEQ_LEN)):
            total_tokens += len([token for seq in labelbt for token in list(filter(lambda x: x!=0, seq))])
            Xbt, ybt, labelbt = [jnp.array(x) for x in (Xbt, ybt, labelbt)]
            Xmask, ymask = [create_mask(x) for x in (Xbt, ybt)]

            model, opt_state, batch_loss = step(model, opt_state, Xbt, ybt, Xmask, ymask, labelbt)
            total_loss += batch_loss
            num_batches += 1

            if num_batches % 20 == 0:
                print(f"Batches trained: {num_batches} | Avg. Batch loss: {total_loss/num_batches}")

        epoch_loss = total_loss / num_batches
        print(f"Epoch {e} | loss: {epoch_loss}")
```

Error:

```py
def _softmax_deprecated(
    478     x: ArrayLike,
    479     axis: Optional[Union[int, tuple[int, ...]]] = -1,
    480     where: Optional[ArrayLike] = None,
    481     initial: Optional[ArrayLike] = None) -> Array:
    482   x_max = jnp.max(x, axis, where=where, initial=initial, keepdims=True)
--> 483   unnormalized = jnp.exp(x - lax.stop_gradient(x_max))
    484   result = unnormalized / jnp.sum(unnormalized, axis, where=where, keepdims=True)
    485   if where is not None:

FloatingPointError: invalid value (nan) encountered in jit(sub)
```

The above problem is encountered only after crossing 200 batches of training. I haven't checked that skipping the specific batch where the error occurs. Maybe I sohuld inspect if some specific inputs are the resason to this error.

But I can't find the answer to the above 3 questions :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions:

> 1. `jax.disable_jit()` does not remove implicit jit compilations.

If this is true, it is a bug and you should report it on the JAX issue tracker. It's unclear from your question what makes you believe this is the case.

> 2. Why does jax.nn.softmax calls _softmax_deprecated by default?

Because `_softmax_deprecated` is the old default algorithm, that will someday be deprecated but the deprecation has not happened yet. See https://github.com/google/jax/pull/15677 for details. To use the newer algorithm, you can set the `jax_softmax_custom_jvp=True` configuration.

> 3. I'm encountering NaNs in subtraction inside _softmax_deprecated: `unnormalized = jnp.exp(x - lax.stop_gradient(x_max))` I'll attach the code for your reference if needed:

You didn't include enough code to reproduce your issue (next time, try to add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to allow others to answer your question without guesswork). But it would be worth setting `jax_softmax_custom_jvp=True` to see if that addresses your issue. The pull request linked above has details.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. I finally resolved my error. It was nothing to do with jax intself. There seem to be a bug in data preprocessing.